# How do I get summary statistics in R after negative selection of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to negatively select (all but the given row value for each level of a factor variable) and summarize the data that remains.  For a simple example, I have a data frame, DF, with two columns.

```
>DF
Category      Value  
A               5  
B               2  
C               3  
A               1  
C               1
```

It would look something like this if dplyr could negative select (can it?).

```
> DF %>% group_by(!Category) %>% summarise(avg = mean(Value))
!Category    avg
A            2.00               #average of all rows where category isn't A
B            2.50
C            2.67
```

Comment: The operation you want can't be done using `group_by` because you would be using each value more than once, so it's not just a simple split of the data frame by a factor. You're going to have to write the code yourself using a more general method like `lapply` or `dplyr::do`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it in base `R`:

**edit**: thanks for suggesting an extensible change @Ryan

```
> sapply(levels(DF$Category), FUN = function(x) mean(subset(DF, Category != x)$Value))

       A        B        C 
2.000000 2.500000 2.666667
```

Comment: I would replace `c('A','B','C')` with `levels(DF$Category)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Or if `Category` was a character vector, you could use `unique(df$Category)`. And if they wanted a `data.frame` in return, you can wrap your suggestion in `stack()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input bouncyball and Ryan. I have been doing so much with dplyr recently I was stuck in that mode of thinking. This solution works and is very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` we can try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, DF[!Category %in% .BY[[1]], mean(Value)], by = Category]
#   Category       V1
#1:        A 2.000000
#2:        B 2.500000
#3:        C 2.666667
```

Comment: or `dt[, dt[!.BY, mean(Value), on="Category"], by=Category]`

Comment: mtoto, this certainly works, but I am very much a newbie WRT data.table. I completed the DT class on DataCamp, but haven't really forced myself to use it. Thanks for provided the answer and a reason to start using DT.

Comment: The main benefits of `data.table` are flexibility and speed. In this case, the `data.table` solution is abour x100 times faster than using `sapply` as above.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using a for loop:

```
DF<-data.frame(Category=c("A","B","C","A","C"),
               Value=c(5,2,3,1,1))

DF2<-data.frame(Category=unique(DF$Category))

for(letter in unique(DF$Category)) {
        DF3<-DF[DF$Category!=letter,]
        DF2$avg[DF2$Category==letter]<-round(mean(DF3$Value),2)
}

DF2

  Category  avg
1        A 2.00
2        B 2.50
3        C 2.67
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. This is how I think, but I am trying to get away from using for loops in R whenever possible... take advantage of vectorized code (speed and clean).